# Struggling with Data Binding Model on post .netCore Razor Pages

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm currently struggling with getting data to bind on a post event.

I'm Using EF core to load data to object which use to load and display the list of data.

```
  <div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        @if (Model.HeadersHasData)
        {
           // unnessary codes 


            @foreach (var item in Model.DisplayDataHeaders)
            {
                <div class="container mb-2">
                    <div class="row border-dark border-top">
                        <div class="col-sm-1">@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.ServiceAbbr)</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.ServiceName)</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.Qty) Hours/IPs/Locations</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.Description) Duration</div>
                    </div>
                    @if (Model.DetailsHasData)
                    {
                        @foreach (var details in Model.DisplayDataDetails)
                        {
                            @if (details.ServiceId == item.ServicesId)
                            {
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input type="hidden"
                                           name="DisplayDataDetails.Index"
                                           value="@details.TaskAssignedId" />
                                    <input type="hidden"
                                           name="DisplayDataDetails[@details.TaskAssignedId].TaskAssignedId"
                                           value="@details.TaskAssignedId" />
                                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                                        <input type="checkbox"
                                               name="DisplayDataDetails[@details.TaskAssignedId].TaskComplete"
                                               value="@details.TaskComplete"
                                               checked=@details.TaskComplete
                                               disabled="@details.AccessGranted" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">@details.TaskName</div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1">@details.TaskStartDate.ToShortDateString()</div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1">@details.TaskEndDate.ToShortDateString()</div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">@details.TechLead</div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">@details.Tech2</div>
                                    <div class="col-sm">@details.Tech3</div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            }

        }
        <button type="submit">Test</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This displays the data and everything correctly.

I'm now working on the interaction for when user change the check-boxes (will eventual try to figure on change event for check-boxes) current useing .

I've applied [bindProperty]  but every-time a debug through DisplayDataDetails object I get an object with a count of 13 which is the correct number of rows expected but all rows are null.

I'm very confused on what I'm missing because everything I've read  on  https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes
 and 
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

shows this should be a very straight forward action.

```
     [BindProperty]
        public List<Detail> DisplayDataDetails { get; set; }

  public async Task OnPostAsync(int? saleId)
        {
            var test = DisplayDataDetails;
            //await LoadDataAsync(saleId);

            var pause= "pause";

        }
```

Any assistants or suggestion will be appreciated.

### Update 1

Just Wanted to add and update,created a separate test project and was able to walk through the Binding Complex Collections example in the https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding I modified the view to match my use case and was able to get data back even with checkboxes values on post back with data-binding.

this works
.cs

```
namespace RazorPages
{
    public class ModeContactTestModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
        public string stubFirstName { get; private set; }
        public string stubLastName { get; private set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
           LoadTestData();
        }

        private void LoadTestData()
        {
            //Contacts = 
            stubFirstName = "john";
            stubLastName = "Doe";
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Contacts.Add(new Contact
                {
                    ContactId = i,
                    FirstName = stubFirstName,
                    LastName = stubLastName,
                    Email = stubFirstName + "." + stubLastName + i + "Test@email.com",
                    Enabled =  (i % 2 == 0) ?  true : false
                });
            }

        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            // process the contacts
        }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

.cshtml

```
@page
@model RazorPages.ModeContactTestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ModelContactTest";
}

<h1>ModelContactTest</h1>
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Enabled</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Contacts.Index" value="@contact.ContactId" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="Contacts[@contact.ContactId].ContactId" value="@contact.ContactId" />
                    @*@contact.ContactId*@
                </td>
                <td><input name="Contacts[@contact.ContactId].FirstName" value="@contact.FirstName" /></td>
                <td><input name="Contacts[@contact.ContactId].LastName" value="@contact.LastName" /></td>
                <td><input name="Contacts[@contact.ContactId].Email" value="@contact.Email" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                           name="Contacts[@contact.ContactId].Enabled" 
                           value="true" 
                           checked="@contact.Enabled"/></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

I create a new demo razorPage to start rewriting my page I started with apples to applies in my working project.... data binding still does not seem to work

which is doesn't make any since as I see nothing different that jumps out at me.

.cs

```
namespace Project.Web.Razor
{
    public class ################: PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }// = new List<Detail>(); //

        public void OnGet()
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            Details = new List<Detail>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Details.Add(new Detail
                {
                    AssignedId = i,
                    Name = "Dev Testing Task " + i,
                    Complete = (i % 2 == 0) ? true : false,
                    StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2019"),
                    EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2019"),
                    Lead = "John Doe",
                    //SaleId = i+1,
                    //ServiceId = i + 2,
                    AccessGranted = (i % 2 == 0) ? true : false,

                });
            }
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            // process the TaskDetails
        }
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        public int AssignedId { get; internal set; }
        public string  Name { get; internal set; }
        public bool Complete { get; internal set; }
        public DateTime  StartDate { get; internal set; }
        public DateTime  EndDate { get; internal set; }
        public string  Lead { get; internal set; }
        public bool AccessGranted { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

.cshtml

```
@page
@model ##########################
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "#####################";
}

<h1>EngagementingDetails</h1>
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        @foreach (var Detail in Model.Details)
        {
            <tr class="row">
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Details.Index" value="@Detail.AssignedId" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="Details[@Detail.AssignedId].AssignedId" value="@Detail.AssignedId" />
                </td>

                <td class="col">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Details[@Detail.AssignedId].Complete" value="true" checked="@Detail.Complete" disabled="@Detail.AccessGranted" />
                </td>
                <td class="col">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Details[@Detail.AssignedId].Name" value="@Detail.Name" />
                    @Detail.Name
                </td>
                <td class="col">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Details[@Detail.AssignedId].StartDate"
                           value="@Detail.StartDate" />
                    @Detail.StartDate.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td class="col">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Details[@Detail.AssignedId].EndDate"
                           value="@Detail.EndDate" />
                    @Detail.EndDate.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td class="col">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Details[@Detail.AssignedId].TechLead"
                           value="@Detail.TechLead" />
                    @Detail.TechLead
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

this is really confusing me why I can get this to work in one project but not anothor it when click update and debug the OnPost event I get returns a list with a count of 5 but each item is null in my working project in the test contract project it returns the list count of 5 with data in each object as expected. Not sure what I'm doing different between the two.

### Update 2

In regards to last comment I made the following changes for testing

.CSHTML

```
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="row">
            <th></th>
            <th class="col">Complete</th>
            <th class="col">Name</th>
            @*<th class="col">StartDate</th>
            <th class="col">EndDate</th>
            <th class="col">Lead</th>*@
        </tr>

        @foreach (var detail in Model.Details)
        {
            <tr class="form-group row">
                <td >
                    <input type="hidden" 
                           name="Details.Index" 
                           value="@detail.AssignedId" />
                    <input type="hidden" 
                           name="Details[@detail.AssignedId].AssignedId" 
                           value="@detail.AssignedId" />
                </td>

                <td class="col">
                    <input class="form-check-input"
                           type="checkbox"
                           name="Details[@detail.AssignedId].Complete"
                           value="true"
                           checked="@detail.Complete"
                           />
                </td>
                <td class="col">
                    <input class="form-control form-control-sm"
                           name="Details[@detail.AssignedId].Name" 
                           value="@detail.Name" readonly />                    
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

.cs

```
  [BindProperty]
        public List<Detail> Details { get; set; } = new List<Detail>(); //

        public void OnGet()
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            //Details = new List<Detail>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Details.Add(new Detail
                {
                    AssignedId = i,
                    Name = "Dev Testing Task " + i,
                    Complete = (i % 2 == 0) ? true : false,
                    //StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2019").AddDays(i + 1).AddMonths((i)+1),
                    //EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2019").AddDays((i + 1) + 15).AddMonths((i) + 1),
                    //Lead = "John Doe",
                    //SaleId = i+1,
                    //ServiceId = i + 2,
                    //AccessGranted = (i % 2 == 0) ? false : true,

                });
            }
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            // process the TaskDetails

            if(Details is null)
            {
                LoadData();
            }else if( Details[0] == null)
            {
                Details = new List<Detail>();
                LoadData();
            }
            else
            {
                Details = new List<Detail>();
                LoadData();
            }



        }
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        public int AssignedId { get; internal set; }
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
        public bool Complete { get; internal set; }
        //public DateTime StartDate { get; internal set; }
        //public DateTime EndDate { get; internal set; }
        //public string Lead { get; internal set; }
        //public bool AccessGranted { get; internal set; }
    }
```

While debugging I'm still returning onPost List Details back with a count of 5 but each item in it is null. ie.  Details[0] = null, Details[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSOf3.png) = null, etc, etc.

Just ran fiddler and it seems to be sending the object

[Fidder Output snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSOf3.png)

Now I'm wondering if the bindproperty is failing to pick up the data on the post event.

Comment: Start by simplifying the data that you return . . . If you only have an Id, a name, and the complete field does it return values?

Comment: @PaulGibson   I simplified objected down to three fields Id, Complete and Name even removed accessGranted that was to disable checkboxes if not login user. I still get a List<details> Details back with a count of 5 which shows it is binding object  but each item is coming back null   Details = count = 5   details[0] = null ,details[1] = null  etc. etc.not sure what this works in my test project and not in this project

Answer (score 0):

### I got it to work

I end-up rewriting it completely from scratch using my Contract test as a template. Testing the binding after each major change. I added a IndexId column to my object so that I could explicitly set the List index which I believe was my  major issue before.  I believe my issue had to do with my two foreach loops I need to to generate the view with out defining an strict index it was causing the binding to fail... that as least what I believe was my issue.

Fineal CSHTML

```
        <form method="post">
            @foreach (var row in Model.DetailsHeaders)
            {
                <table class="table table-sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">@Html.DisplayFor(c => row.ServiceAbbr)</th>
                            <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">@Html.DisplayFor(c => row.ServiceName)</th>
                            <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">@Html.DisplayFor(c => row.Qty) Hours/IPs/Locations</th>
                            <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">@Html.DisplayFor(c => row.Description) Duration</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var detail in Model.Details)
                        {
                            if (detail.ServiceId == row.ServicesId)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="row">
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details.IndexId"
                                               value="@detail.IndexId" />
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].IndexId"
                                               value="@detail.IndexId" />
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].AssignedId"
                                               value="@detail.AssignedId" />
                                        @*@Html.DisplayFor(r => detail.AssignedId)*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].Complete"
                                               value="true"
                                               checked="@detail.Complete"
                                               disabled="@detail.EditAccess" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].Name"
                                               value="@detail.Name"
                                               readonly />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(r => detail.Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].StartDate"
                                               value="@detail.StartDate"
                                               readonly />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(r => detail.StartDate)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].EndDate"
                                               value="@detail.EndDate"
                                               readonly />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(r => detail.EndDate)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].LeadTech"
                                               value="@detail.LeadTech"
                                               readonly />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(r => detail.LeadTech)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].Tech2"
                                               value="@detail.Tech2"
                                               readonly />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(r => detail.Tech2)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="Details[@detail.IndexId].Tech3"
                                               value="@detail.Tech3"
                                               readonly />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(r => detail.Tech3)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
            <button>Update</button>
        </form>
```